# Will I have deadlocks while using laravel DB transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, transactions, deadlock

I am using MySQL and Laravel. Imagine situation when I have two transaction executing at the same tame, first updates table1 and table2 in the following order. second transaction updates table2 and table1 in the following order. so I have 3 scenarios and I am interested which of these scenarios will happen.

```
T1 - transaction 1;

T2 - transaction 2;
```

**1 scenario)** T1 locks table1. meanwhile T2 locks table2. both table are locked. after some time both of them will unlock their locked table so T1 will be able to modify table1 and T2 will be able to modify table1. everything is finished, no deadlocks.

**2 scenario)** situation is the same as above but T1 and T2 will not unlock their tables unless they finished all their work (i mean modified both table). they are waiting infinitely for the second table to be unlocked. so deadlock.

**3 scenario)** T1 or T2 locks both table, so second transaction will wait until concurrent transaction finishes it's work and unlockes both tables. then it also lockes both table and everything is fine, no deadlocks.

which of these scenarios will happen? maybe none of them? I hope you guys will help me to answer on this question, so that I will know weather I should manage code to avoid transaction deadlocks or laravel transaction will do this by itself and I just use transactions and don't think about deadlocks. thank you in advance.